# Recurring loss of CREATE SYNONYM permissions for a user in TEMPDB

Tags: sql-server

I'm experiencing a recurring problem whereby a user's CREATE SYNONYM permissions within TEMPDB are being lost.  Is there a reason why these permissions do not seem to be permanently persistent?

The error I am getting:

```
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): CREATE SYNONYM
> permission denied in database 'tempdb'
```

Comment: tempdb is recreated from scratch everytime sql server is restarted, whatever was there won't be there anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I left you the comment but what you can do is the following

create a proc in the master database, in that proc give the permissions for the tempdb (you can use USE tempdb in the proc if you use dynamic sql)

then mark the proc to run at startup

```
exec sp_procoption N'MyProcName', 'startup', 'on'
```

Now everytime sql server is restarted, this proc will run and give the permissions

See also here [List all stored procedures that run at startup in SQL Server](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/MSSQLServerAdmin/list-all-stored-procedures-that)

Answer (score 0):

tempdb is created as a copy of the model database every time the server is restarted. My guess is that there's a server restart happening between when you grant the permission to the user and when you get this error message. That said, you can either grant the permission in model and it will be in tempdb when the server restarts or you can do something like creating a startup stored procedure to grant the permission in tempdb.

Comment: re: "grant the permission in model" - can you expand on this a bit? I realize that tempdb gets wiped, but that permissions do as well is a bit confusing;  if I wanted a user to permanently have  db_ddladmin permissions in tempdb, without recreating after each restart, how/where would one grant that permission?

Comment: ...from what I read, if db_ddladmin is granted in modeldb, then that permission will be granted in ALL newly created db's, correct?  There must be a way to permanently set tempdb permissions without running a script on server startup, no?

Comment: You have the right of it re: permissions on new databases inheriting from model. Because tempdb is re-created every time the server starts, it behaves no differently in this respect.